# how to activate virtual env in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I cant activate virtual env in vs code. I tried same code in the cmd console is work but not in the vs code terminal.

"D:\python\djangoapp\djangovenv\Scripts\activate.bat" I write this code.

I am using windows 10 pro

Comment: see here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Is the terminal in VSCode Command Prompt or PowerShell? Activating a PowerShell virtual environment is different than Command Prompt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah Its beacuse of terminal vs code was using powershell ı changed with cmd

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 15):

You need to switch your Python interpreter to point to the one within your venv when you switch the interpreter VS code it create a **.vscode** folder within your workspace with a **settings.json** indicating the python interpreter. This will give VS code the direction of where to locate the venv.

You can follow these steps

**Step 1:** Enter Ctrl+Shift+P in your vs code.

**Step 2:** Locate your Virtual Environment:

[[image: Select Interpreter]]

**Python: select interpreter > Enter interpreter path > Find**

**Step 3:** Once you locate your virtual env select your python version:

**your-virtual-env > bin > python3.**

**Step 4 :** Now in your project you will see .vscode directory created open settings.json inside of it and add:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

don't forget to add a comma before to separate it with the already present key-value pair.

**Step 5:** Now restart the terminal.

Your virtual environment is activated automatically.

Comment: yeah ı tried it to but  I am using windows. İn windows there is not a bin folder but my terminal was the powershell . I change it with the command promt but thanks for thr suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can also change your default terminal in VS Code, by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `Terminal: Select Default Profile` and choose a terminal for your needs.

I was using PowerShell and I wanted to activate virtual environment, but it always gave me an error, so I switch from PowerShell to Command Prompt, and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the terminal settings from  PowerShell to CommandPrompt, it will work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MqxQ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's the same as the answer from 2021: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69086039/2745495